# If i have an image within a button, and the button's width increases on hover, how do I keep the image's position fixed where it was initially?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

When I hover over the button it changes as desired in terms of width, however the image is shifted towards the center. I want to keep it fixed on the left so that it doesn't shift over when the width of the button changes. Here is my code. I am building with React:

```
<div>
        <button
          className={
            this.state.activecut === true
              ? "designstudiobuttonleftopactive"
              : "designstudiobuttonlefttop"
          }
          onClick={this.cutActiveHandler}
        >
          <img src={shirtlogo} id="cutlogo" alt="" />
        </button>
</div>

.designstudiobuttonlefttop {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid #574904;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: white;
 color: #574904;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 50px;
 }

.designstudiobuttonlefttop:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: #574904 !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition-delay: 100ms !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

#cutlogo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.designstudiobuttonleftopactive {
  color: #574904 !important;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `text-align: center;` to `text-align: left;` (for both classes)

Answer (score 0):

i am not familiar with react syntax but it can be achieved by putting button inside an additional `div` within same block.

yet there are many more ways to achieve it , also without using another div.
see an example

http://jsfiddle.net/wa2vht71/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use `float: left` to keep it on the left side of the button.

```css
.designstudiobuttonlefttop {
 width: 60px;
 height: 60px;
 margin-top: 150px;
 display: block;
 border: 1px solid #574904;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: white;
 color: #574904;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: 50px;
 }

.designstudiobuttonlefttop:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: #574904 !important;
  text-decoration: underline;
  transition-delay: 100ms !important;
  cursor: pointer !important;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}

#cutlogo {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.designstudiobuttonleftopactive {
  color: #574904 !important;
  border: none;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: 100px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
        <button
          class="designstudiobuttonlefttop"
          onClick={this.cutActiveHandler}
        >
          <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT6vxI3cA6w8ocAr3KWNHdMmq5gkkhYSuacNYaFCrQxZmeBUo2m" id="cutlogo" alt="" width="40" height="40" style="float: left;"/>
        </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox, the following code sample keeps your image to the left regardless of your button width:

```
<div class="button">
  <div class="imageContainer">
    <img src="path/to/your/image" />
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    .button {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        width: 100px;
    }
    .button:hover {
        width: 200px;
    }
    .button .imageContainer {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        align-self: center;
    }
    .imageContainer img {
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```